# echo javascript in heredoc php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to echo the javascript from php in a heredoc.  But its not working because of dollar sign. Escaped the dollar sign but it's still not working . Could anyone help out regarding this. Thanks. It gives an error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

```
<?php 
    echo '<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head><title> hello world </title> </head> <body>' ;
        $testscript=<<<EOT
        <script>
            \$('input[type=radio][name=gender]').change(function() {
                 alert(this.value);
            });
        </script>
        EOT;
        echo $testscript;
    echo '</body></html>' ;

?>
```

Comment: Add `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` You haven't referenced jQuery library

Comment: You can use jQuery in place of $ for javascript section

Comment: jQuery hasn't loaded, hence undefined error. Either change it to `jQuery(...).change(..`. Or run on DOM load - `jQuery(document).ready(function(){  ...do your stuff..  });`

Comment: It is not PHP's error. You just did not load jQuery within your page.

Comment: Missed the jquery library.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jquery library was not loaded  in the script